# NullPointerException não sei como resolver

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Estou fazendo uma classe casa e uma classe porta, e na classe casa estou declarando 3 portas e quando vou executar dá NullPointerException, alguém poderia me dar uma luz

classe da minha porta

```
package introducaoclasses;

public class Porta {

 boolean aberta;
 String cor;
 int dx, dy, dz;

 public void abrePorta() {
    this.aberta = true;
 }

 public void fechaPorta() {
    this.aberta = false;
 }

 public void pinta(String nova) {
    this.cor = nova;
 }

 public boolean estaAberta() {
    return this.aberta;
 }
}
```

Minha casa

```
package introducaoclasses;

 public class Casa {

 Porta porta1, porta2, porta3;
 String cor;

 public void pintarCasa(String Cor) {
    this.cor = Cor;
 }

 public int quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() {
    int cont = 0;
    if (porta1.estaAberta()) {
        cont++;
    }
    if (porta2.estaAberta()) {
        cont++;
    }
    if (porta3.estaAberta()) {
        cont++;
    }
    return cont;
 }
}
```

Minha classe principal

```
package introducaoclasses;

  public class IntroducaoClasses {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Casa nova = new Casa();
    nova.porta3.abrePorta();
  }

}
```

Comment: Você não esta instanciando as portas em nenhum momento, você poderia fazer isso no construtor da classe `Casa`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua classe `Casa`, você não instanciou as portas. Faça isso:

```
package introducaoclasses;

public class Casa {

    private Porta porta1 = new Porta();
    private Porta porta2 = new Porta();
    private Porta porta3 = new Porta();
    private String cor;

    public void pintarCasa(String novaCor) {
        this.cor = novaCor;
    }

    public int quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() {
        int cont = 0;
        if (porta1.estaAberta()) {
            cont++;
        }
        if (porta2.estaAberta()) {
            cont++;
        }
        if (porta3.estaAberta()) {
            cont++;
        }
        return cont;
    }
}
```

Comment: Era isso obrigado